# Events are not triggered when view is declared at model's default

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

**Background**

I am working in a agenda web app where the user can select the "day", "week" and "month" view. For first steps, I have created a `Scheduler` that will contain a `DayView` object, simple as I can. So, I have started with this html markup (ignored head section just for clarify the code source):

```
<body id="mjb-calendar">
    <div data-role="page" id="mjb-day-view">
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <a class="test" href="#">Test</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have create the `day model` model and `day view` as follow:

```
var Day = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        title: "Day"
    }
});

var DayView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#mjb-day-view',
    events: {
        "click .test": 'test'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model = new Day();
        this.model.on('change', this.render);
    },
    test: function(){
        alert('test');
    },

    render: function() {
        console.log('day view rendered');
        return this;
    }
});
```

Ok, please notice that there is an event that is triggered when the element `.test` is clicked. So, proceed to run a test:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var day = new DayView();
});
```

Once the the `.test` link is clicked, the alert is prompted correctly.

Well, in order to make the scheduler more flexible, I created it as follow:

```
var Scheduler = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "view": new DayView()
    }
});

var SchedulerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#mjb-calendar',
    events: {},

    initialize: function(options) {

        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.model = new Scheduler();
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.model.get('view').render();
    }
});
```

Notice that I have declared the `DayView` as an attribute of Scheduler model (`"view": new DayView()`).

**The problem**

When I initialize a Scheduler view as...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var scheduler = new SchedulerView();
});
```

... why does not `click .test` event is not longer triggered?

**assets**

- underscore 1.7.0
- backbone 1.1.2
- jquery 2.1.3

Comment: There are things better to avoid to do in the code like Model should not contain View but the code should work.http://jsfiddle.net/7mMGp/62/

Comment: if you declare a new instance in the default all models will share that same instance, i imagine this is not what is desired as each model will want it's own view

Comment: @suish, I get the point,  but stills not working

Comment: @quince, but scheduler object at this scenario only will be instantiated once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comment.
The code should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/7mMGp/64/

```
 var Day = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
         title: "Day"
     }
 });

 var DayView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el: '#mjb-day-view',
     events: {
         "click .test": 'test'
     },

     initialize: function() {
         _.bindAll(this, 'render');
         this.model = new Day();
         this.model.on('change', this.render);
     },
     test: function(){
         alert('test');
     },

     render: function() {
         console.log('day view rendered');
         return this;
     }
 });

 var Scheduler = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
         "view": new DayView()
     }
 });

 var SchedulerView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el: '#mjb-calendar',
     events: {},

     initialize: function(options) {

         _.bindAll(this, 'render');
         this.model = new Scheduler();
         this.render();
     },

     render: function() {
         this.model.get('view').render();
     }
 });

 var schedulerView = new SchedulerView();
```

According to the code you put,You have to make an instance of schedulerView at first.

then `schedulerView`'s `initialize` do `new Scheduler()` which makes `DayView` instance at its initialize.

So the program flow is

schedulerView(main View) -> schedulerModel -> DayView -> DayModel

This ain't good design but works.

FYI,You can do something like this instead.

```
var Days = Backbone.Collection.extend({
 model: Day
});
var days = new Days()
//add or modify the Collection
```

and in the SchedulerView,

```
render : function(){
  days.each(function(dayModel){
    new DayView({model : dayModel}).render();
  })
  return this
}
```

mainView(SchedulerView) makes subViews(DayView) instance with `dayModel`s and call their `render`

simple relationship.